# Can I annotate a PDF with gImageReader to make it searchable?

Tags: windows-10, ocr, tesseract-ocr

I am using the latest version of gImageMaker (3-2023, Windows 10). OCR works fine.

I use a PDF as source, which is not searchable and just want to add the OCR text to the PDF so it becomes searchable.

So far I have only been able to create a new PDF with the text. But I want to keep the original PDF, just annotated with the OCR text.

Any chance to do that with gImageMaker?

---

References:

1. [How to search a PDF where text is just image?](https://superuser.com/questions/700372/how-to-search-a-pdf-where-text-is-just-image)
2. [Looking for a good annotation tool for PDF documents on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/155181/looking-for-a-good-annotation-tool-for-pdf-documents-on-windows)

Comment: Did you try Adobe Acrobat?  You can add annotated text in Acrobat. This may accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: If I want to edit or just add text, I need the commercial version. I can add notes, but those do not appear to be searchable.